# Калькулятор на C++

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    double n1;
    double n2;
    char s;
    cout << "Enter: ";
    cin >> n1;
    cin >> s;
    cin >> n2;
    switch(s)
    {
        case '*': {
            double total1 = n1 * n2;
            cout << total1;
        }
        case '/': {
            double total2 = n1 / n2;
            cout << total2;
        }
        case '+': {
            double total3 = n1 + n2;
            cout << total3;
        }
        case '-': {
            double total4 = n1 - n2;
            cout << total4;
        }
    }
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Здравствуйте, я написал мини калькулятор на C++ и вот запускаю код и пишу числа и в ответ мне выдает лишние числа (например я написал 2*2, и мне вывело это 4140, также случается и с другими числами но уже не выводит 140 а что то другое например 250) что мне делать я не могу никак решить проблему, жду ответа, оценю того кто поможет

Comment: [break statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break)

Comment: Ну а если добавить после каждого `case` — `break`? 4140 — это результат умножения, деления, сложения и вычитания двух двоек, записанные подряд...

Answer (score 1):

```
switch(s)
{
    case '*': {
        double total1 = n1 * n2;
        cout << total1;
    }
    break; // !!!!!
    case '/': {
        double total2 = n1 / n2;
        cout << total2;
    }
    break; // !!!!!
    case '+': {
        double total3 = n1 + n2;
        cout << total3;
    }
    break; // !!!!!
    case '-': {
        double total4 = n1 - n2;
        cout << total4;
    }
    break; // !!!!!
}
```

Обратите вниманеи на `break`, которые не позволяют коду перейти к следующему `case`. И хорошо бы написать хоть какую-то защиту "от дурака" — неверного ввода. Хотя бы ветку `default`.